# Replacing certain text in product description

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, data-replication

My website is `www.officialphonerepairco.uk` , the problem that I am having is :

I put address on all the product description, and I have about 5000 products. Now to delete the address from each product description is a time taking. So, is there any easy method to select all the products and then delete the address from all the product description.

Any Help with this problem will be highly appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Hi Deepak, were you able to find solution for your usecase? I'm also faced with similar problem of replacing text in product description.

Answer (score 1):

You go to `Product -> Catalog` and view my [screencast](https://goo.gl/iNwnK2).
You select all products from the list and select from 'Action' field select 'Update Attributes' and you can modify the value of all product attributes.

Try the SQL code in your database:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_text SET value = REPLACE(value, 'Somthing', 'Somthing else') WHERE attribute_id = 75 AND value LIKE '%Somthing%';
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply , if I am doing that the problem I am having is, everything on the description is getting changed to  same text but I want to remove just the address and keep the rest. Please check this link it has address https://www.officialphonerepair.co.uk/catalog/product/view/id/3194/s/front-screen-repair-sony-sony-xperia-z5-compact/ Thank

Comment: I edited my answer with your requirements. Please try.

Comment: I have tested this works. Additionally, i used the where clause that was generated by  search utility of phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

I would use a REPLACE in mysql.

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, 'http:://something', '')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%http:://something';
```

I can't remember if the table that stores the descriptions is still catalog_product_entity_text in M2. (I don't have it on my phone). Make sure to test and make backups!

Comment: Hi thank you for you reply and help I will try that today.